# NSPredicate with NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate

I'm trying to create an `NSPredicate` with `NSDate`s to query my core data db. I'm forming the predicate in a method that pieces together an `NSMutableString` named `filterString`. `queryCount` is an `NSInteger` that keeps track of how many queries are appended. In the block below, `start` and `end` are `NSDate`s

```
if (start || end)
    {
        if (!queryCount)
        {
            [filterString appendString:@"("];
        }
        else
        {
            [filterString appendString:@" && ("];
        }

        // date range and exact date
        if (start && end)
        {
            [filterString appendFormat:@"%@ >= %@ && %@ <= %@", kTransactionFilterDateKey, start, kTransactionFilterDateKey, end];
        }
        // only start
        else if (start && !end)
        {
            [filterString appendFormat:@"%@ >= %@ && %@ <= %@", kTransactionFilterDateKey, start, kTransactionFilterDateKey, [NSDate distantFuture]];
        }
        // only end
        else if (end && !start)
        {
            [filterString appendFormat:@"%@ >= %@ && %@ <= %@", kTransactionFilterDateKey, [NSDate distantPast], kTransactionFilterDateKey, end];
        }

        [filterString appendString:@")"];

        queryCount++;
    }
```

When I reach the block that forms the actual predicate object (`self.currentFilterString` refers to the method where the above block is from):

```
- (NSPredicate*)currentPredicate
{
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:self.currentFilterString];
}
```

I get the error `"Unable to parse the format string "(date >= 2014-09-24 04:00:00 +0000 && date <= 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000)""`

This is the result for the block above labeled `//only start`. The other blocks result in the same. I've tried using different date values instead of `distantFuture`, but that doesn't change anything either.

I've also tried a variation that was like `"%@ BETWEEN %@", kTransactionFilterDateKey, @[start, end]` but that gave me the same error.

Is this the correct format for an `NSPredicate` using a date or is there a different way to do it? Everything I found online lead me to think I just put the `NSDate` object into the formatted string like I'm doing.

Comment: One thing you could try is to create multiple individual predicates and set a compound predicate:     [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pred1, pred2]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When comparing dates, NSPredicate is picky with the key format. When I created the predicate manually using `%K` for the key and putting the formatted string directly in `predicateWithFormat:` instead of `%@` in an already formatted string that I pass in it works. So I reworked my solution to create a formatted string with `%K` as the key placeholder and created an array of arguments that I can pass into `predicateWithFormat:arguments`